# How do I create my own method to change a string in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
module SessionsHelper 
def store_location 
  session[:path] = request.path if request.get?
end
```

This returns `'/friends'` or `'/users'` or `'/new'` etc. I want to remove the '/' from the beginning of it.

I then tried to add into `module SessionsHelper` the following method:

```
def removal() 
  self[1..self.length]
end
```

and changed the `store_location` method to:

```
session[:path] = request.path.removal() if request.get?
```

but I am getting the following error:

> NoMethodError (undefined method `removal()' for "/friends":String):

So then after searching it looks I need to do something with `class String` but I am uncertain how to set this up properly.

Comment: You don't need to add any method to string class. `path.sub(/^\//,'')` should do.